# call single css menu in multiple html pages

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of creating a website.

I have a menu bar which is common for all the pages. I want to call the HTML page which contains the menu bar from any page within my site.

Is there any syntax to include HTML files so that I can solve my issue.

If so how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML Template File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518760/html-template-file)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use php extension for you files instead of html and call your header with

```
<?php include_once('header.php'); ?>
```

where you want header to be displayed

If you are working on local machine install [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or you will not be able to see your website because php is server side scripting language

Comment: thx for your replz :) but the problem is this i am not useing any local machine b/c its a simple html website i am not useing any server side language in it :(

Answer (score 0):

** Answer from other questions **

You are describing [server side includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes).

> Server Side Includes are useful for including a common piece of code throughout a site, such as a page header, a page footer and a navigation menu.

Example of usage:

```
<!--#include virtual="../quote.txt" -->
```

This will add the text of `quote.txt` to the page - if you add it to multiple pages, you can make your change in this one file and it will show on all pages in was included in.

Different web servers have different support and additional features for these, so you need to check the documentation for yours.

Many websites that need dynamic features (like fetching data from a database) will use some kind of server side scripting language for this kind of functionality - examples include PHP, Perl, ASP.NET, JSP and many more.