# How can I replace html elements with php?

Tags: php, html

I have a website in which I use just html, but I'd like to add one location where I would edit things like the nav and the footer. Then it would be instantly updated across the whole site.

So, for example, I'd like to put:

```html
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Into

```html
<?php echo $nav;?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! =)

Comment: http://php.net/require_once

Comment: `$nav = '<nav>....</nav>';`

Comment: possible duplicate of [call single css menu in multiple html pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11027738/call-single-css-menu-in-multiple-html-pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the html that you want to show into a file. For eg:

add this to menu.html

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Now include this page in other HTML pages wherever you want to call it like below

```
<?php
    include 'menu.html';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Lal's answer. I would change `include 'menu.html';` with `include_once 'menu.php';` The idea is that you will can add some php variables if you need them on some point.....