# <UL> Menu in single file, then call it in all HTML web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my html web page I have designed menu as a UL (Unordered List)

Now I have multiple pages. In case I add one menu item, then I have to edit all web pages.

I simply want that I could create my menu UL (unordered list) in a separate file i.e.  js file (or any other file) and call it in my all html web pages. 
So that when ever I have to add a new item in my menu, I would simply add menu item in one file; rather then editing all html web pages.

Please give me any solution or guide me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP my friend, PHP

Comment: What is your server language ?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518760/html-template-file

Comment: if you are using php as a server language the it will be easy.

Comment: this is a simple static website having html pages with css and js only.

Comment: You could use AJAX to do this, but it would be susceptible to FOUC and not a very good idea. Ideally you would use server-side includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to replicate this code in all your html files.

```
<body>
    <ul class='my-list'></ul>
</body>
```

Js:

```
var list = `<li>Dummy 1</li><li>Dummy 2</li>`;
$(".my-list").append(list);
```

This could be one of the many ways, but i think this is the easiest one to do your job. You will only need to change the JS code whenever you want to add a new list item.

Comment: Salute you. But sir can I also use all other tags i am using in my list like :             <li>
            <a href="quality-policy.html"> <img  class="opacity-low"  src="images/sub_menu_aboutus_qp.png" alt="Objectives"> </a>
          </li>

Comment: Yes, you are free to do that. Just make sure your javascript file runs after the dom has completely loaded. Use .ready() function in jqeury on the document to achieve that.

Comment: So nice of you Sir, This has resolved my problem and i am also using javascript files to cater and manage common contents in a centralized way.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `w3-include-html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>

<body>

<div w3-include-html="content.html"></div> 

<script>
w3IncludeHTML();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

**OR**

Make a `json` file and use it for creating your menu with javascript.